# Which months in Japan probability lowest of natural disaster?

Tags: predictability

I want travel Japan but it gets earth quakes, tsunamis, typhoons. Which months lowest probability of these natural disasters?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disasters_in_Japan_by_death_toll might be a place to start researching, but remember that past performance doesn't imply future performance.

Comment: There is no way to predict earthquakes or tsunamis. They are not cyclic over short duration time frames -  they happen when they happen. Typhoon season in Japan is from May to October, with the peak period being August & September.

Answer (score 3):

There is no season for earthquakes or tsunamis. They can hit at any time of the year, and at any time of the day or night.

Typhoons happen in the warm season, but they will be forecast by the meteorological service, giving you time to move to a safe area.

If you want to go to Japan, just go. It is better to go in the season you want to go than to try and avoid earthquakes and typhoons, as they happen in random places out of anybody's control.